# iPhone fail-safe multiple files download

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, download, jpeg

My app is downloading packages of images from a server. It's an array of direct links (20-50 files) from XML.

- How do I make sure the whole set of images is fully downloaded?
- How do I add a condition to cancel whole download (and remove all already downloaded files) if app was closed with iPhone button? (such methods are in AppDelegate while my whole download code is in some downloadviewcontroller.m)
- Anything else I have to worry about while downloading several files? (5-10 MB in total)

The code I currently use isn't very safe in case of download interrupting or app closing. In background thread I'm calling this method for each file:

```
    (BOOL) loadImageFromURL:(NSString *)url withName:(NSString *)filename toFolder:(NSString *)folder {

        NSURL *link = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
        NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];    
        NSString *filepath = [folder stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];

        if ([manager fileExistsAtPath:filepath]) {
            return YES;
        }
        else
        { 
            UIImage *image = [[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:link]] retain];
            NSData *data = [NSData dataWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0f)];
            if ([data length] <= 0) 
                [image release];
                return NO; // no data
            else 
            {
                [data writeToFile:filepath atomically:YES];
                [image release];            
                return YES;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use nsoperation to do so

check out blow [link](http://www.cimgf.com/2008/02/16/cocoa-tutorial-nsoperation-and-nsoperationqueue/)..

http://www.cimgf.com/2008/02/16/cocoa-tutorial-nsoperation-and-nsoperationqueue/

now on august 2012 try to search wwdc 2012 video no 211 to learn nsoperation. 
u can use block to do so.

```
[aNsque addExecutionBlock:^{ ...code... }];
```

where aNsque is nsblockoperation.

Answer (score 2):

Dont use the synchronous call `dataWithContentsOfURL`.  Instead look at how to use the asynchronous method of NSURLConnection, [– initWithRequest:delegate:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURLConnection/initWithRequest%3adelegate%3a)

You can then cancel the request with `[connection cancel];`  Also you will not have to run it on another thread because it is already asynchronous.

As far as having multiple requests running, you probably have a few options. One idea would be to create an abject that starts the NSURLConnection and parses the response,  then create an array of theses objects.

Comment: Do I use one NSURLConnection for one file and just go with files one by one? I didn't really see any good example for multiple files and I've already read the NSURLConnection documentation before. I'm using this dataWithContentsOfURL in other thread for now and it works great (3 lines of code instead of implementing 3+ methods) but I worry about the connection interruption or app closing.